# Class Mage not found in Shell Script on some servers

Tags: debugging, shell

We have a custom script in `shell` with 
`require_once 'abstract.php';` and our class extends `Mage_Shell_Abstract`.

On our dev environments this is working fine, but on staging we get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/foo/public/shell/abstract.php on line 86
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: are you using modman?

Comment: We use composer on the dev environment. But on the target machine no composer is used.

Comment: @Alex, have you diagnosed the issue and found any solution?

Comment: We found out that a mixture of absolute and relative paths in the require_once statements caused problems and resolved it by adding __DIR__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a PHP bug caused by mixing relative and absolute paths. See stackexchange https://stackoverflow.com/q/26885077/288568

Comment: Hi alex is this issue now solved?